# Local files with relative paths are not loading in NodeJS Express app

Tags: node.js, express, static-files

I'm trying to build an app in Express and Node.js. My server files are contained in the `app` folder and the frontend stuff is in the public folder.

My file structure is like:

```
my_project
|- app
|     |-(server stuff)
|     |- ....
|- public
|     |- modules
|     |     |- core
|     |     |     |- index.html
|     |     |     |- style
|     |     |     |     |style.css
|     |     |     |     |sidebar.css
|     |     |     |- img
|     |     |     |     |- faceicon.png
|     |     |     |     |- main.png
|     |     |     |- js
|     |     |     |     |main.js
|     |     |     |     |sidebar.js
|     |     |- articles
|     |     |     |- ....
```

**The problem is** that in my `index.html` file, when I reference a file like

```
<link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

or in my `style.css` like

```
background: url(../img/faceicon.jpg) no-repeat bottom center scroll;
```

The expected result doesn't show on the screen, and I get console messages like

```
GET http://localhost:3000/img/faceicon.png 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Seems like you don't have a `css` folder.

Comment: @AleksandrM sorry, fixed that

Comment: Image path should be `http://localhost:3000/modules/core/img/faceicon.png`

Comment: @Sami but what if I would then change the port for my server? This link would then no longer work right?

Comment: @Sami But I shouldn't have to. `index.html` is in the same directory as `img`. It theoretically should work with `img/faceicon.png`

Comment: It should work. I tried a similar setup and it is working for me. I guess you have it enabled `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[express.static](http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.built-in) middleware is based on [serve-static](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static?_ga=1.185104169.1059149982.1422847790), and is responsible for serving the static assets of an Express application.

How it works:

- Serve static content for the app from the "public" directory in the application directory

  // GET /style.css etc

  **app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));**
- Mount the middleware at "/static" to serve static content only when their request path is prefixed with "/static"

  // GET /static/style.css etc.

  **app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));**
- Serve static files from multiple directories, but give precedence to "./public" over the others

  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/files'));

  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/uploads'));